# Evaluating low-temperature dependence of the BCS gap function

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, approximations, many-body

How does one go about evaluating the behavior of the BCS gap $ \Delta = \Delta(T) $ for $ T \to 0^+ $ under the weak coupling approximation $ \Delta/\hbar\omega_D \ll 1 $?

In Fetter & Walecka, *Quantum theory of Many-Particle Systems*, Prob. 13.9 it is said that the starting point is
$$\tag{1}  \ln\frac{\Delta_0}{\Delta} = 2\int_0^{\hbar\omega_D}{\frac{\mathrm d\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^2+\Delta^2}}\frac{1}{e^{\beta\sqrt{\xi^2+\Delta^2}}+1}}, $$
which I have no problem deriving from the theory, but I can't find a way to actually evaluate this integral even under the approximations $ \hbar\omega_D \to \infty $, $ \Delta \approx \Delta_0 $ (in the RHS) and $ \beta\Delta \to \infty $. [Of course $ \beta = (k_BT)^{-1} $ and $ \Delta_0 = \Delta(T = 0)$.]
I have tried several approaches, used different Taylor-expansions and changes of variables, but I am simply stuck.

For the record, the expected behavior is supposed to be
$$\tag{2} \Delta(T) \sim \Delta_0\left(1 - \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\beta\Delta_0}}e^{-\beta\Delta_0}\right) .$$

EDIT: Just leaving it here for the posterity. I found a more complete way to tackle this integral; specifically, under the WC approximation one has
$$ \int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm d x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}\frac{e^{-\beta\Delta\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}}{1 + e^{-\beta\Delta\sqrt{x^2 + 1}}}} = \int_1^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm d y}{\sqrt{y^2 - 1}}\frac{e^{-\beta\Delta y}}{1 + e^{-\beta\Delta y}}} = $$
$$ = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\int_1^{+\infty}{\frac{\mathrm d y}{\sqrt{y^2 - 1}} (-1)^{k+1}e^{-k\beta\Delta y}} = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1}\int_0^{+\infty}{\mathrm d t\; e^{-k\beta\Delta \cosh{t}}} = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^{k+1} K_0(k\beta\Delta), $$

$ K_0 $ being the 0-order [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://books.google.it/books?id=Mlk3FrNoEVoC&pg=PA181&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false), whose asymptotic behavior is known and may be used to solve the problem in a relatively clean way (and even find the corrections at higher orders, which are $ \in O(e^{-\beta\Delta}(\beta\Delta)^{-k - 1/2}) $. Cf. Abrikosov, Gorkov, Dzyaloshinski, *Methods of Quantum Field Theory in Statistical Phyisics*, 1963. Pagg. 303-304.

Comment: I guess the answer of this question is contained in an old answer of mine: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/65444/16689 please tell me if you need more details.

Comment: @FraSchelle: I did read that post, but I couldn't find this specific problem addressed. I might have missed it, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

1. Define difference $\delta:=\Delta-\Delta_0$. Deduce from $|\delta|\ll |\Delta_0|$ that the lhs. of eq. (1) is $$\tag{A}\text{lhs}~\approx~ -\frac{\delta}{\Delta_0}.$$
2. Substitute $\xi=x\Delta $ in the integral on the rhs. of eq. (1). Deduce using $\hbar \omega_D \gg \Delta$ that the rhs. is
   $$\tag{B} \text{rhs}~\approx~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}} \frac{1}{e^{\beta\Delta \sqrt{1+x^2}}+1}.  $$
3. Deduce from $\beta\Delta\gg 1$ that we can simplify the rhs. further to a Gaussian integral
   $$\tag{C} \text{rhs}~\approx~ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \! dx~ e^{-\beta\Delta (1+\frac{1}{2}x^2)}~=~\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\beta\Delta}}e^{-\beta\Delta} .  $$
   Such arguments are closely related to the [method of steepest descent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_steepest_descent).
4. Deduce eq. (2).

Comment: I see, so $ x $ should be treated as a small quantity in the integrand because $ e^{-\beta\Delta} $ warrants doing so. Thank you very much, this had been bugging me for a while.